# Azure resource to check orphan resource

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am looking solution to find out Stopped | Deallocated resources  Orphan Resources in Azure. I grab the VM data. But if someone spins the VM and VM showing running, How to check owner not used that VM since 30 Days.

```
az vm list  -d --output table
```

Any automation suggestion will be welcome.

```
az vm list  -d --output table

TESTSXG                                                      VM running
```

Comment: no way of doing that

Comment: Any way to identify, if some create any resource(VM, storage, nic, disk) and forget to deallocate. I can identify an orphan resource.

Comment: how do you know if its being used or not? you cant, pretty obvious

Comment: I mean cheek last login in VM if that is older than 30 days. I can say no one using that.

Comment: why? you dont need to login to vm to use, it might run jenkins for example? thats a really shallow approach. also, you cant check last login to vm, because there is no way Azure can know that

Comment: can we check anything from Azure portal? reason due to lazy folks, they created VM and forget to inform us, Now it's really difficult to identify, which VM not used by them. Is any approach, Like if someone(machine or code) not using resource since 30 days that will auto deallocate

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple queries here.

1. To identify if someone created any resource (say VM) and has forgot to deallocate it.
2. To check last login in VM if it is older than 30 days.
3. To check owner not used the VM(s) in the last 30 days.
4. If we don’t login to VM since a while and if some services (like Jenkins, etc.) are running and untouched.

To audit actions on resources and to determine the operations that were taken on resources, you may use Activity Logs. For more information refer this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit) link.

**For #1**, You may execute the below command.

```
Get-AzureRmVM -Status|select Name, PowerState
```

**For #2 and #3**, below is the command which you can run manually in the VM.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | 
Sort-Object -Property LastLogon -Descending | 
Select-Object -Property * -First 1 | 
Where-Object {$_.LastLogon -match "(\d{14})"} | 
Foreach-Object { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name=$_.Name;LastLogon=[datetime]::ParseExact($matches[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)}}
```

But I know that we are looking for an automated way to validate all the VM’s under your subscription. So here the requirement is to automatically (i.e., remotely) connect to all the ‘running’ VM’s from Azure portal and then get the required output. If i am not wrong, most probably we can achieve this requirement in multiple ways i.e.,

i.   Log Analytics

ii.  DSC

iii. Functions

iv.  Runbook

v.   Logic App

i.   Create a Log Analytics OMS workspace and install OMS agent on the VM(s) as instructed here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm). Then add Azure Security Center (Security and Audit) solution in OMS so that the security events will be pushed to OMS repository. Then goto Log Analytics -> OMSworkspaceName -> Logs and run the below Kusto query to get the required output.

```
SecurityEvent
| where EventID == 4624 
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

Note that the Event ID 4624 is the ID for the event log of any account logged on to a machine.

ii.   Onboard Azure DSC on the VM(s) as instructed here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding) and write a DSC configuration script using ‘script’ DSC resource which will run the above mentioned Get-WmiObject…. command remotely on the DSC nodes (i.e., VM’s) and fetch us the required output.

iii.   Write a HTTP trigger PowerShell function which will run the above mentioned Get-WmiObject…. command remotely (i.e., may be try a new ps session and invoke command) on the VM’s and fetch us the required output. You may refer this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) link to learn about Functions.

iv.   Write a PowerShell runbook which will run the above mentioned Get-WmiObject…. command remotely (i.e., may be try new ps session and invoke command) on the VM’s and fetch us the required output.

v.   Currently Azure Logic Apps seems not support to run PowerShell and CLI script. However, we may try to use available Logic Apps Functions connector or any similar connector and internally try to call PowerShell to execute above mentioned Get-WmiObject…. command remotely. Just FYI here (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33913552-run-a-powershell-code-within-a-logic-app-action) is a voice in Azure feedback regarding running PowerShell code within a Logic App, you could vote if you are interested in this option.

**For #4**, Install OMS agent on the VM’s so that the events details get stored in OMS repository. For example, if no one is logging in to a VM but Jenkins service is running on that VM then in that case you may want to not disturb that VM. So, to validate if Jenkins service is running on a VM or not you may have to run a Kusto query something like this.

```
Event
| where (EventLog == "System")
| where (RenderedDescription has "jenkins" and RenderedDescription has "stopped")
```

Hope this helps!!